# Como usar o round do python

Tags: python, arredondamento

Quando eu uso o round do python ele converte  1.5 parar 2, mas com 2.5 ele deixa 2. Como faço para ele arredondar 2.5 para 3 ? Sendo que qualquer outro número que não contenha o número 2 ele arredonda certinho

Comment: Acesse este [Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/375544/como-arredondar-numeros-decimais-para-o-maior-inteiro-python/461877#461877).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `round` leva o seu valor ao número inteiro par mais próximo.

Para arredondar pra cima, use o `math.ceil`:

```
import math
print(math.ceil(1.5))  # 2.0
print(math.ceil(2.5))  # 3.0
```

Para arredondar 0.5 pra cima e 0.49999 pra baixo, você pode fazer uma função com o módulo `decimal`:

```
import decimal

def arredondar(x):
    return int(decimal.Decimal(x).quantize(0, decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP))

print(arredondar(1.5))  # 2
print(arredondar(2.5))  # 3
print(arredondar(1.4))  # 1
print(arredondar(2.4))  # 2
```

Comment: mas ai eu não consigo fazer o que eu quero. Eu quero digitar um numero e se a casa depois do '.' for menor que 4 arredondar pra baixa e se for maior que 5 arredondar pra cima. Você saberia como eu posso fazer isso ?

Comment: @Coelho veja se agora entendi; editei a resposta!

Comment: Obrigado amigo.

Comment: @Coelho por nada! Não esqueça de aceitar a resposta se ela respondeu a sua pergunta.