# Como arredondar numeros decimais para o maior inteiro? python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou precisando `arredondar` valores `decimais` para o maior valor inteiro `mais próximo` do respectivo valor em questão.

Por exemplo, tenho o valor...

```
22.6
```

...e gostaria de receber como resultado o valor...

```
23
```

Como posso realizar esta operação em `Python`?.

O algoritmo no qual desejo implementar esta operação se encontra listado, logo abaixo.

```
for i in range(len(lista)):
    if lista[i][0] == esp:
        contador += lista[i][2]/lista[i][1]
        ocorrencias += 1
print(pca*(contador/ocorrencias))
esp, pca = input().split()
```

faco algumas operações com lista e sempre obtenho um valo próximo ao correto, com alguns algarismos decimais abaixo

Comment: Duplicada de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/317381/5878

Answer (score 2):

Importe a biblioteca `math`, e nela existem duas funções, a `floor()` e a `ceil()`, a `floor()` arredonda para baixo e a `ceil()` arredonda para o inteiro mais próximo para cima

```
math.floor(30.4)
(30.0)

math.ceil(30.4)
(31.0)
```

Edit: Mais Exemplos:

```
math.floor(99.1)
(99.0)

math.ceil(99.1)
(100.0)

math.floor(22.4)
(22.0)

math.ceil(22.4)
(23.0)
```

Comment: Quero mais 2 exemplos. +1

Comment: feito, foi adicionado no edit

Answer (score 0):

O que você está querendo calcular é, nada mais, nada menos que o `teto` de um número.

O `teto` de um número `real` (que pode ser um número de ponto flutuante) é o `menor` número `inteiro` maior que o referido valor real.

Exemplo 01:

O `teto` de `22.6` é `23`

Pois o `menor` número inteiro `superior` ao número real de valor `22.6` tem como resultado o número `23`

Exemplo 02:

O `teto` de `-22.6` é `-22`

Pois o `menor` número inteiro `superior` ao número real de valor `-22.6` tem como resultado o número `-22.

**Antes de tomar alguma decisão diante deste 2º exemplo** deves observa a `direção` na disposição dos valores na [reta real](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_real).

Na `reta real` os números são distribuídos no `sentido` da `esquerda` para a `direita`. Em outras palavras, dado um número real **N**, todo número `maior` que `N` será colocado à sua `direita`...

```
22.6, 27.0 29.6, 30.4...
```

...todo número `menor` que `N` será colocado à sua `esquerda`...

```
...16.0, 17.5, 20.0, 22.4, 22.6
```

Diante desta explicação podemos ver agora nitidamente o resultado do `2º exemplo`, isto é,

```
-25.0, -24.7, -22.6, -22.0, -21.5, ...
```

Ou seja, como o valor **-22** está posicionado à direita de **-22.6**. isto significa dizer que o `teto` de `-22.6` é o número `-22`.

Agora, após toda esta explicação, como podemos calcular o `teto` de um número com o `Python`?

Para se calcular o `teto` de um número em `Python` é necessário executarmos o método `ceil` da classe `math`.

Para mostrar o funcionamento desse `método` desenvolvi o seguinte algoritmo...

```
from math import ceil

lista = [15.3, 16.3, 17.9, 21.4, 22.5, 25.6, 26.9]

resultado = list()
for numero in lista:
    # Calculando os valores dos Tetos de cada valor contido em "lista".
    resultado.append(ceil(numero))

print(f'\033[32mOs valores dos Tetos são: {resultado}\033[m')
```

Veja o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/rwkpieef-solkarped)

Observe que este algoritmo calcula e exibe o valor do `teto` de todos os valores da lista anterior.

Observe também, que o resultado da função `ceil` sempre será um valor `inteiro`.